# How to send Row values in QueryString through link button in Template column?

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have a situation here. I have a gridView control and there are four columns in it. The fourth column is a template column containing a link button.
What I want is that I want to get the values of the row against which the details link would be clicked. 
e.g I have a

**Employee Name**  **Details**
  Peter              Details
  Jhon               Details

so when ever I click details for peter for example I want peter's name to be sent in the querystring. i know that I can take a hyperlink column and can do it by its DataNavigateUrlfield and DataNavigateFormatString property and I don't need that due to some requirement since I also have to send some other values in the querystring too. Please help me in this regard.

Regards

FAS

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this article on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479316.aspx. In the article a dropdown is added to the column instead of the link but the technique is the same. Basicly you want to implement the ItemDataBound event so that for every row that is bound to the grid you can execute some custom logic. In your case adding the link to the column.